# How to set up SSH passwordless key authentication for remote access only, allowing local users to use passwords

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, authentication, public-key

I am trying to get an SSH server running Ubuntu 10.04 to allow password logons only when coming from the local network.  For all other users, especially those logging in from the internet via the firewall, I want to force Key based authentication.  I googled around and found the following.

Here's what I have changed in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
Match Address 192.168.5.0/24
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

With that, I log in from another machine that has a 192.168.5. address, but it won't allow me in for lack of a publicKey:
Permission denied (publickey).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
Match Address 192.168.5.* PasswordAuthentication yes
```

The first two lines will enable pubkey authentication by default. The last line will override the other two lines for the matched network (192.168.5.0/24).

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, the third line only overrides the second line -- local network users will still have the option to use pubkey authentication if they so choose, but can also elect to use their password instead. Personally, though, I see absolutely nothing wrong with that -- you're allowing passwords for users on the local network, requiring pubkey for users outside the local network, and as an added bonus allowing local users the option to use the exact same authentication method they use outside.

Answer (score 2):

The newline after the match condition is significant. This should work:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
Match Address 192.168.5.0/24
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

EDIT: I'm surprised the other answer worked! It didn't work for me. Well, this way you should be able to use a CIDR netmask.

Comment: The only thing I edited in my file was to change
192.168.5.0/24 
to
192.168.5*

And that got it working.  I left the newline which I originally had.

Comment: It must be something version-dependent - it seems OpenSSH 5.8 at least enforces the newline and allows CIDR netmasks.